# XML tags missing while decrypting in PHP

Tags: php

I'm encrypting a XML along with tag in Java using AES 128 and perform base64 encoding. Then I try to decrypt encrypted data in PHP using same key. I only get the data within the tag decrypted but not the entire XML structure. I require the entire XML structure which I pass in Java for encryption.

Below is my PHP decrypt snippet.

```
public function decrypt($code) {
    // $code = $this->hex2bin($code);
    $iv = $this->iv;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($code);
    $order = $dom->documentElement;
    foreach ($order->childNodes AS $node) {
        if ($node->nodeName == 'encrypted') {
            /* Get Initialization Vector */
            $iv = base64_decode($node->getAttribute('iv'));

            /* Get data, and decode it */
            $data = base64_decode($node->nodeValue);
            $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);
            mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
            $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $data);
            mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
            mcrypt_module_close($td);
            // $decrypted = new SimpleXMLElement($decrypted);
            //$decrypted = simplexml_load_string($decrypted);
            $frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();

            /* Functionality available in PHP 5.1 */
            $frag->appendXML($decrypted);
            /* Replacement node */
            $order->replaceChild($frag, $node);
            break;
        }
    }

    print $dom->saveXML();  
    // $ut = utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
    return $dom;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the structure is really missing? It looks more likely that you're looking at the output in a browser and telling it to try to parse the XML as if it were HTML.

Comment: My actual data-->   <a>test</a>  .This is my encrypted data-> Hq5yjWGIwJXpfPn/BRbwjg==  after Decrypted with php i got  test,but expected result is <a>test</a>

Comment: I suggest you make a simple test script with hard-coded encrypted value and IV. And use var_dump to see the output. I think the problem has nothing to do with encryption, but either in the process of generating the encrypted string or the way how it's used afterwards.

Comment: Encryption by using java and php are same. When decrypting with php only got the result as above, not as expected.

Comment: I have replaced '<' and '>' with "&lt;" and "&gt;" like this  `&lt;a&gt;hello&lt;a&gt;` in php and changes done on java as well.Now working as expected. Any other better solution for this?